# Find the Statistical Mode on multiple columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Customer Location Table Like Below.

```
CREATE TABLE CusLoc ( 
  person_id   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  Base_Location_M1 VARCHAR2(100), 
  Base_Location_M2 VARCHAR2(100), 
  Base_Location_M3 VARCHAR2(100), 
  Base_Location_M4 VARCHAR2(100), 
  Base_Location_M5 VARCHAR2(100), 
  Base_Location_M6 VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO CusLoc 
VALUES (123, 'London', 'Paris', 'London', 'Paris','London', 'Spain');

INSERT INTO CusLoc 
VALUES (134, 'Oslo', 'Dubai', 'Oslo', 'Dubai','Oslo', 'Dubai');
```

I want to create 2 more columns. Column '*Most_Used_Base_Location_T3*' and 'Most_Used_Base_Location_T6' which will calculate the statistical mode of the occurrences of the location and populate the columns at a person_id level.

For the first record, i.e person_id 123, the expected result is 'London' for *Most_Used_Base_Location_T3* and 'London' as well for *Most_Used_Base_Location_T6*.

For the secondrecord, i.e person_id 134, the expected result is 'Oslo' for *Most_Used_Base_Location_T3* and if there is a tie like in last six months, Both 'Dubai' and 'Oslo' has appeared equal number of time then
*Most_Used_Base_Location_T6* should take the latest month value i.e 'Oslo'

NB: *M1 is the latest Month & M6 is the oldest
*T3 is the statistical mode of M1,M2 and M3
*T6 is the statistical mode of M1,M2,M3,M4,M5 and M6

Comment: Horrible table design. Have one Base_Location column only. (And perhaps a visitcount column too.)

Comment: MySQL is not Oracle and Oracle is not MySQL. Please, use appropriate tags. Because of `varchar2` it looks like you use Oracle

Comment: What is T3 and T6? What's the difference between them?

Comment: "should take the latest month value i.e 'Oslo'" - which one is the latest month: `M1` or `M6`? M1?

Comment: Edited the Post for better clarification

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways is to use unpivot + [`FIRST` or `LAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) aggregate functions:

```sql
select
   v.person_id,
   max(b3)keep(dense_rank first order by cnt desc, a) Most_Used_Base_Location_T3,
   max(b)keep(dense_rank first order by cnt desc, a) Most_Used_Base_Location_T6
from (
   select
      c.*
     ,case when a in ('M1','M2','M3') then b end b3
     ,count(*)over(partition by b) cnt 
   from CusLoc
   unpivot(
     b for a in (
        Base_Location_M1 as 'M1',
        Base_Location_M2 as 'M2',
        Base_Location_M3 as 'M3',
        Base_Location_M4 as 'M4',
        Base_Location_M5 as 'M5',
        Base_Location_M6 as 'M6'
     )
   ) c
) v
group by person_id
/
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa2d34936824e18dff16a79bc2a19586): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa2d34936824e18dff16a79bc2a19586

**Updated as per new info:**

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbf1b1da2ac07844599f3a34ab81b5d6)

```
select
   v.id,
   max(b3)keep(dense_rank first order by cnt3 desc, a) Most_Used_Base_Location_T3,
   max(b)keep(dense_rank first order by cnt desc, a) Most_Used_Base_Location_T8
from (
   select
      id,a,b
     ,b3
     ,count(b3)over(partition by id,b3) cnt3
     ,count(b )over(partition by id,b) cnt
   from (
       select 
           id,a
          ,nullif(b,'NA') as b
          ,case when a in ('M1','M2','M3') then nullif(b,'NA') end b3
       from test_mug1
       unpivot(
         b for a in (
            T1_MUG_Data as 'M1',
            T2_MUG_Data as 'M2',
            T3_MUG_Data as 'M3',
            T4_MUG_Data as 'M4',
            T5_MUG_Data as 'M5',
            T6_MUG_Data as 'M6',
            T7_MUG_Data as 'M7',
            T8_MUG_Data as 'M8'
         )
       )
   ) c
) v
group by id
order by id
```

Comment: When i tried this on a larger set of data, it's not giving the expected output. Moreover I see lot of null values. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23fdad2f2548aa9e19d733784f9d08d5

Comment: @RakeshDas should you count `NA` as a city or consider it as null?

Comment: If as a city: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=54484efd61e7735aad4e6317d0c826e6

Comment: @RakeshDas and if you need to ignore `NA`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e6e8a4f86106e8c520212e32136ced6